# Javascript editors and console.log

Tags: javascript, console

I used several editors for javaScript and i write

```
var firstName = "John";
console.log(firstName);
```

problem is that i do not get `console.log` in Chrome (or other browser)

anyone knows what might happening?

Comment: Are you sure the code is running?

Comment: do you write it in script tags, or if you write it in a js file is it added on html file that you are opening.

Comment: Copy&paste your code directly into your chrome-console and check if you can see the log. If not you might have set a filter.

Comment: Can you make an integral example, from <doctype> to </html>?

Comment: i wrote it directly in my browser and the answer is "undefined"

Comment: @keravnos that code is correct you're doing something wrong

Comment: yes there is something with chrome i think!!!

Comment: @keravnos no its not with chrome

Comment: Do you get a console log here https://codepen.io/SehaxX/pen/dKBQpP?editors=1111

Comment: No man,i dont get any console log in the link you pasted!

Comment: @keravnos screenshot?

Comment: have you maybe disabled javascript in dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

Simply writing:

`var firstName = "John"; console.log(firstName);`

Isn't enough for javascript to run. Javascript is a scripting language meaning you need to provide some other infrastructure for it to work. In this case that infrastructure is `HTML`. You can use `HTML` and Javascript together like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
    var firstName = "John"; console.log(firstName);
  </script>
</html>
```

The `script` tags indicate that you are writing Javascript. Save this file as a `.html` file and then right-click your file and click view in chrome. Then check the console for results

Comment: ah i write it directly and save it as a .js file i think i can do that!

Comment: If you write `var firstName = "John"; console.log(firstName);` directly with no script tags, then that is fine if you save it as a .js
But, if you do that, you cannot right-click the .js file and view it in chrome. You first must link it to a HTML document, and then view that HTML document.

Comment: @keravnos no worries, don’t forget to mark the question answered if it works. Also, in case you didn’t know you can link .js files in ur HTML file by doing <script src=“fileName.js”></script>

Comment: saved it as html script but still chrome doesnt show answer.I used the link that someone sent here to check if chrome console gives answer directly from the link and chrome console didnt work.So it must be a chrome problem!

Comment: Hm, strange, make sure your using the latest version of chrome, also try opening the HTML page in a different browser such as Safari/Internet Explorer and see if their consoles output anything

Comment: i did that with the !doctype html that you placed above and didntl work.I am beliving that  it is an chrome problem.Chrome console doesnt answer a thing

Comment: wait!firefox worked.It writes that it is a matter of character encoding

Comment: So does Firefox give you what you were expecting? Or does it give you some sort of error?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- You have saved the file (something like index.html)
- You have the correct file open in the browser
- You have put the js inside a script tag